# Migrating from WordPress to Craft CMS

Tags: craft-pro, import, plugin-feedme

I am trying to migrate blog posts from WordPress to Craft CMS through the [Feed Me](https://github.com/engram-design/FeedMe) plugin.

First, I export posts in .xml file from Wordpress. Then, I import in Craft CMS.

All things are good except the category and tags. It imports the category and tags from .xml file but it is not able to separate the category and tags.

Here the few code of category and tags means how it look in .xml

```
<category domain="post_tag" nicename="computer"><![CDATA[computer]]></category>
<category domain="post_tag" nicename="corporate"><![CDATA[corporate]]></category>
<category domain="post_tag" nicename="employee"><![CDATA[employee]]></category>
<category domain="post_tag" nicename="expert"><![CDATA[expert]]></category>
<category domain="post_tag" nicename="forensics"><![CDATA[Forensics]]></category>
category domain="category" nicename="forensics"><![CDATA[Forensics]]></category>
<category domain="category" nicename="infosec-training"><![CDATA[InfoSec Training]]></category>
<category domain="post_tag" nicename="warlock"><![CDATA[warlock]]></category>
<category domain="post_tag" nicename="witness"><![CDATA[witness]]></category>
```

And also the screen shot of mapping and and how it looks in section.

Mapping
[image]

Section View
[image]

**How can I separate these?**

Answer (score 2):

Feed Me currently doesn't support this, as sometimes your data is contained in attributes, so it needs to be able to access that. Crucially, the tags are the same value, which is what trips things up.

Have you looked at the Wordpress to Craft guide? https://sgroup.com.au/plugins/feedme/guides/migrating-from-wordpress

Comment: The link is dead